# I would like to look up two values to return the value in a specific row

Tags: excel, datatables, lookup

I would like to look up the value in the right-hand table based on the value in Column L as well as the value in that row that is at least the value in column H, and return the value in row 2 of the right-hand table.

[image]
Example: find where 2% (from column L) is on the right-hand table, find the column that is at least 2,333,10, and return 30 mph.

Comment: INDEX & MATCH maybe

Comment: vlookup and index w/ a match but they're giving me a value of #value.

Comment: How do you want to handle non-exact entries? e.g. what if proposed is 2.1%? This value does not appear in the table to the right. Do you want to round up or round down (or return an error)?

Comment: For example, the value 1 does not appear in the table on the right but that will change. Every value in Ciolumn L will appear in column P. I'm just looking for the format because I'm not sure what I don't understand about applying the match and index functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type the following array formula into cell `M8`:

```
= INDEX($Q$4:$U$4,MATCH(TRUE,MMULT(TRANSPOSE($Q$5:$U$11),(L8=$P$5:$P$11)+0)>H8,0))
```

Note, this is an array formula, so you must press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the keyboard after typing it instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also note: This is just sample ranges for a simplified example. You will have to modify the ranges to however far your data extends.

See below for a basic working example. Also in the example below, I dragged this formula down to cell `M9` to demonstrate it works when you drag down. I just used sample data because I didn't want to type out all of your data but it returns the expected result.

[image]